# Can't run Kotlin tests with Eclipse Junit run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, kotlin

Am having a weird issue where a Junit Run Configuration that was running my Junit tests for months just stopped working and now it can no longer see/find the test.KotlinTestsRunner class (see the pics [1] and [2] for more details).

[1] - https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=getfile&id=35978& 
[2] - https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=getfile&id=35979&

Seems like it's a Kotlin classpath issue (Java tests run just fine, see below) but the task's Dependencies tab contains the Kotlin build directories where Kotlin main and test classes are located:

`../Kgt-4/build/classes/kotlin/main
 ../Kgt-4/build/classes/kotlin/test`

Eclipse says it "Can not find test class 'test.KotlinTestsRunner' in project 'Kgt-4' (see the pics above) but the test.KotlinTestsRunner is there:

`$ ls -l Kgt-4/build/classes/kotlin/test/test/KotlinTestsRunner.class 
-rw-r--r-- 1 luser luser 762 Jul 21 13:02 Kgt-4/build/classes/kotlin/test/test/KotlinTestsRunner.class`

Strangely, I can run my Kotlin tests if I set up a Java application run configuration with the same classpath Junit run configuration and it runs without issues. I can also my Java tests in test.JavaTestsRunner class with the same Junit configuration (the only difference is the test class name, obviously) without any issues. Here's how the command line looks like in this case:

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -ea -Dfile.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968 -classpath /home/luser/Work/Kgt-4/build/classes/kotlin/main:/home/luser/Work/Kgt-4/build/classes/kotlin/test:/home/luser/Work/Kgt-4/build/classes/java/main:/home/luser/Work/Kgt-4/build/classes/java/test:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.41/e24bd38de28a326cce8b1f0d61e809e9a92dad6a/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.41.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.41/2ecf4aa059427d7186312fd1736afedf7972e7f7/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.41.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test-junit/1.3.41/2ec43deb5225811cb0fd63385b7f9382a78cd225/kotlin-test-junit-1.3.41.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test/1.3.41/98efd6e69ef6f877b086dfd7894a4c36fe5d5736/kotlin-test-1.3.41.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.12/2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec/junit-4.12.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test-annotations-common/1.3.41/f57e03dea3d1a81b5e1b3cdcf4eb2710a3fac173/kotlin-test-annotations-common-1.3.41.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-test-common/1.3.41/744000c1a0ef654706ce3367a10543590dab9246/kotlin-test-common-1.3.41.jar:/home/luser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/luser/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.12.0_297942815_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/403/0/.cp:/home/luser/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.12.0_297942815_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/402/0/.cp org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 39669 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames test.JavaTestsRunner`

`$ ls -l Kgt-4/build/classes/java/test/test/JavaTestsRunner.class 
-rw-r--r-- 1 luser luser 666 Jul 21 13:02 Kgt-4/build/classes/java/test/test/JavaTestsRunner.class`

The issue appeared first on 2019-3R, I then moved to 2019-6R but the issue is still there.

Any ideas? Thanks